# getting data from div Class

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

All the data is in Div class . I have written some code to access the first class to extract data but its now working kindly have a look at code.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.olx.com.pk/items?page=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
rows = soup.select("ba608fb8 de8df3a3.li")
all_data = []
for row in rows:
    price = row.find_all("div", class_="_7978e49c _2e82a662")
    all_data.append[(price)]
print(all_data)
```

Comment: Hey can please mention what error or problem are you facing in code ??

Comment: It's not returning any output just giving out the empty dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issue in your code:

- You have to select the `<ul>` with the class name - `ba608fb8 de8df3a3`
- Then find out all the `<li>` using `find_all()` method
- The prices are inside the `<span>` tag with class name - `_7978e49c _2e82a662`. Select them and get the text out of it.
- To append a value to a list - `all_data.append(price)` and not what you have in your code.

Here is the code that gets the prices from the URL.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.olx.com.pk/items?page=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
rows = soup.find('ul', class_="ba608fb8 de8df3a3").find_all('li')
all_data = []
for row in rows:
    temp = row.find("span", class_="_7978e49c _2e82a662")
    if temp:
        price = temp.text.strip()
        all_data.append(price)
print(all_data)
```

```
['Rs 98,000', 'Rs 2,200,000', 'Rs 29,999', 'Rs 12,800', 'Rs 30,000', 'Rs 28,000', 'Rs 18,500', 'Rs 3,500', 'Rs 225,000', 'Rs 22,000', 'Rs 2,180,000', 'Rs 4,000', 'Rs 1,600,000', 'Rs 210,000', 'Rs 24,000', 'Rs 25,000', 'Rs 18,000']
```